# la4j not calculating SVD of matrix correctly?

Tags: java, linear-algebra, la4j

I have the following matrix:

```
 0.003,0.013,0.022,0.013,0.003
 0.013,0.060,0.098,0.060,0.013
 0.022,0.098,0.162,0.098,0.022
 0.013,0.060,0.098,0.060,0.013
 0.003,0.013,0.022,0.013,0.003
```

I'm trying to use la4j to calculate its singular value decomposition, using this code:

```
  SingularValueDecompositor SVD = new SingularValueDecompositor(A);
  Matrix[] factorization = SVD.decompose();

  Matrix U = factorization[0];
  Matrix D = factorization[1];
  Matrix V = factorization[2];
```

However, 
the result for U, D, V in order is:

```
0.102,-0.826, 0.307,-0.456,-0.071
0.456,-0.175,-0.859,-0.155,-0.017
0.751, 0.423, 0.374,-0.337,-0.059
0.456,-0.320, 0.166, 0.740, 0.339
0.102,-0.076, 0.029, 0.327,-0.936

-----------
.2873094460,.0000000000,.0000000000,.0000000000,.0000000000
.0000000000,.0000000000,.0000000000,.0000000000,.0000000000
.0000000000,.0000000000,.0000000000,.0000000000,.0000000000
.0000000000,.0000000000,.0000000000,.0000000000,.0000000000
.0000000000,.0000000000,.0000000000,.0000000000,.0000000000

-----------
0.102,-0.051, 0.975,-0.148,-0.122
0.456, 0.870, 0.030, 0.186, 0.027
0.751,-0.481,-0.015, 0.374, 0.253
0.456,-0.079,-0.221,-0.627,-0.586
0.102, 0.061,-0.009,-0.640, 0.759
```

and these three matrices multiply to

```
0.003,-0.001,0.028,-0.004,-0.004
0.013,-0.007,0.128,-0.019,-0.016
0.022,-0.011,0.210,-0.032,-0.026
0.013,-0.007,0.128,-0.019,-0.016
0.003,-0.001,0.028,-0.004,-0.004
```

which is not A. I think part of the problem may be the actual diagonal singular values are less than 0.001 (other than the first one), so they do not appear. (The reason the decimals are 10 digits is because I set the decimal format to be that). My question is, how do I get around this issue and get all the singular values to show up?

Answer (score 1):

The singular value decomposition tries to decompose matrix `A` into `A = U * D * V'` where `V'` is the transpose of `V`.

```
// Instead of 
A = U.multiply(D.multiply(V));

// Try
A = U.multiply(D.multiply(V.transpose()));

// You should get back:
0.0030    0.0134    0.0220    0.0134    0.0030
0.0134    0.0597    0.0984    0.0597    0.0134
0.0220    0.0984    0.1620    0.0984    0.0220
0.0134    0.0597    0.0984    0.0597    0.0134
0.0030    0.0134    0.0220    0.0134    0.0030
```